# After encrypting a file, using the same encryption method and entering a different password, the file is decrypted

Tags: mount, password, encryption, ecryptfs

With the encryption tool I downloaded, I encrypt a file with the command `sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils`. After performing the operations, I use the `umount` command and encrypt the .txt files in the file, but when I apply the same operation to the same file and say "mount", it asks for a password, so I enter it intentionally. The password is different. After these operations are done, the txt files in the file can be read in their original form.

My question is:

1. Shouldn't the access be blocked when I enter a different password?
2. Even if the access is not blocked, shouldn't the txt files in the file remain unreadable?

In such a case, there is no point in encrypting the files and anyone who wants to access my personal information can follow this procedure and find my information without the need for a password.

The method I followed is also shown on this site:
https://computingforgeeks.com/encrypt-files-and-directories-on-linux-using-ecryptfs/

Comment: You must have set something up incorrectly or are incorrect about the encrypted status because if a file is encrypted and locked and you do not supply the correct credentials, you will not be able to decrypt and read the file

Comment: As I mentioned above, I just directly applied the method shown on https://computingforgeeks.com/encrypt-files-and-directories-on-linux-using-ecryptfs/. Please correct if there is something missing or wrong or suggest a document that does this. Also I'musing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Yes, I am saying that you either missed something or the guide is bad. Full disk encryption (set up during system installation) is a better option anyway if you are concerned that someone may gain access to your device. Encrypting single files is not very effective especially since lots of software duplicates the kinds of files that include personal information (like documents and spreadsheets)

Comment: Hi @Nmath I solved the problem thank you for your quick replies. I solved the problem by turning the device on and off a few times after doing the encryption process.